# Is it required to set final instance variables in immutable class if copy of mutable objects is returned by getters

Tags: java

Is it required to declare the instance variables as final while creating immutable class provided there are no public setters and private access?

Comment: You should maybe add a simple code sample of what you mean, for clarity.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I was just trying to get what actually final does on the instance fields. And now I think it is for the developer sake not to commit any blunder himself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required, as in the compiler won't compile if you don't. But if the variable is immutable, adding final will make your intent clear to other programmers (and yourself when you look at the code again tomorrow and wonder about it), may help the compiler generate more efficient code and will make the compiler complain if later on you do try to change the variable, which may be helpful of course and may indicate that the code change is maybe not ideal, and that you should think of an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not required: since the private variables are not accessible from subclasses, your class would remain immutable as long as your own code does not violate the immutability rule.

This said, it is certainly a good thing to mark these variables `final` to protect your code from mistakes of someone else<sup>*</sup> maintaining your code.

<sup>*</sup> or even your own mistakes two years from now, when you forget a lot of the details about your class.